# Openssl s_server DTLSv1.2 is not working with certificate RSA-PSS

Tags: openssl, rsa, tls1.2, dtls

I have some issue using DTLS with **RSA-PSS** certificate.

My end entity certificate with rsa-pss key and signed with rsa-pss signature algorithm:
My end entity is enrolled under my root certificate CA_ROOT_PKCS1_5.crt
Certificate extract:
....
Subject Public Key Info:
Public Key Algorithm: rsassaPss
RSA-PSS Public-Key: (2048 bit)
...
Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
Hash Algorithm: sha512
Mask Algorithm: mgf1 with sha512
Salt Length: 0x01BE
Trailer Field: 0xBC (default)
...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IQRp.jpg)

For the test purpose, i use the same Key pair at both client and server side.

I do **TLSv1.2** connection (tls mutual authentication) between a client and a server:

`openssl s_server -cert ee_underRoot_pss_sign_pss.crt -key ee_pss_RSA.key -CAfile CA_ROOT_PKCS1_5.crt -tls1_2 -accept 127.0.0.1:30000 -security_debug_verbose`

`openssl s_client -showcerts -tls1_2 -cert ee_underRoot_pss_sign_pss.crt -key ee_pss_RSA.key -CAfile CA_ROOT_PKCS1_5.crt -connect 127.0.0.1:30000 -security_debug_verbose`

Everything is working well !

I try now to do the same thing but in **DTLSv1.2**:

`openssl s_server -cert ee_underRoot_pss_sign_pss.crt -key ee_pss_RSA.key -CAfile CA_ROOT_PKCS1_5.crt -dtls1_2 -accept 127.0.0.1:30000 -security_debug_verbose`

`openssl s_client -showcerts -dtls1_2 -cert ee_underRoot_pss_sign_pss.crt -key ee_pss_RSA.key -CAfile CA_ROOT_PKCS1_5.crt -connect 127.0.0.1:30000 -security_debug_verbose`

but the handshake failed with the following error: "no shared cipher"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LinaP.png)

When i look at the ciphersuites supported by the client, there is the same list that when i did with TLS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Oqa.jpg)

Here the trace at server side:

```
verify depth is 10, must return a certificate
Using default temp DH parameters
Security callback: Certificate chain EE key=RSA-PSS, bits=2048, security bits=112: yes
Security callback: Certificate chain CA digest=RSASSA-PSS, security bits=256: yes
ACCEPT
Security callback: Version=???: yes
Security callback: Version=???: yes
Security callback: Version=???: yes
Security callback: : yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=256: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algid=9, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algid=10, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algid=11, security bits=256: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algid=4, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algid=5, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algid=6, security bits=256: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algorithm=RSA, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algorithm=RSA, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algorithm=RSA, security bits=256: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA224, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=112: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA1, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=80: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA224, algorithm=RSA, security bits=112: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA1, algorithm=RSA, security bits=80: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA224, algorithm=DSA, security bits=112: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA1, algorithm=DSA, security bits=80: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algorithm=DSA, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algorithm=DSA, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algorithm=DSA, security bits=256: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=256: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algid=9, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algid=10, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algid=11, security bits=256: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algid=4, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algid=5, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algid=6, security bits=256: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algorithm=RSA, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algorithm=RSA, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algorithm=RSA, security bits=256: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA224, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=112: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA1, algorithm=ECDSA, security bits=80: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA224, algorithm=RSA, security bits=112: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA1, algorithm=RSA, security bits=80: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA224, algorithm=DSA, security bits=112: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA1, algorithm=DSA, security bits=80: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA256, algorithm=DSA, security bits=128: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA384, algorithm=DSA, security bits=192: yes
Security callback: Shared Signature Algorithm digest=SHA512, algorithm=DSA, security bits=256: yes
ERROR
540409864:error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher:ssl/statem/statem_srvr.c:2263:
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
```

(if instead, i use certificate containing a "public key rsaencryption" instead of "public key rsapss", DTLS works)

I do not understand why it is working with TLS1.2 but not with DTLS1.2. Could you help me ?

(I have the issue with both openssl1.1.1 and openssl3.0)'

Answer (score 1):

I can't prove a negative -- and although this is about code I'm not certain it's really ontopic -- but I suspect it's because **nothing says it *should* work**.

Neither 5246 nor 6347 said anyting about PSS (although 4055 back in 2005 implemented it, and also OAEP, in PKIX *certs*, which are linked to TLS and DTLS to some extent). 8446 requires protocol signatures use PSS (if RSA) and prefers certificates to do so (sigals and sigalgs-cert) in [4.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.html#section-4.2.3) and states that

```
   -  Implementations that advertise support for RSASSA-PSS (which is
      mandatory in TLS 1.3) MUST be prepared to accept a signature using
      that scheme even when TLS 1.2 is negotiated.  In TLS 1.2,
      RSASSA-PSS is used with RSA cipher suites.
```

also reaffirmed in [1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.html#section-1.3). No similar statement is made about using PSS in DTLS 1.2, and the only reference to 6347 is about using cookie to offload HRR state.

At any rate, that's what [the code implements](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/ssl/ssl_lib.c#L3424) -- a PSS cert-and-key enables selection of a 1.2 suite with aRSA only in *TLS* version 1.2 not (any) DTLS.

Note DTLS 1.3 implementation (which must use PSS, and might provide it for 1.2 as a 'bonus') [only recently got started](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/13900) and as it will presumably require API changes and 3.2 is already in beta it will probably have to wait for 3.3 at least.